# OnTaskCreated Sharepoint 2010 statemachine workflow not firing (Micorsoft Bug!!)

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity

Workflow Scenario:

State-A create task-A and we get OnTaskCreated event, where onchange of task-A we goto State-B where in it we created Task-B, now we are facing problem with Task-B as its OnTaskCreated event as its not firing, does any one know why ?

As we goggled its a known issue faced by many and its Microsoft bug !!!

Now What We Want:

To Get Created Task-B TaskID and its Splistitem

where on CreateTask-B we do get taskID from listitemID property of CreateTask but getitembyid return "task not exist or deleted", is there a way to commit imediately after createtask ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're NOT using system account when creating those workflows. The security update for SP2010 blocks work flows from automatically starting. Weird, I know. Use a different account for the application pool you're experiencing trouble with.

Comment: Hi Thanks..yes i am running with system account ...but i can not change it for some reasons :(.

Answer (score 0):

Now i am not using OntaskCreated activity because of its problems, just using CreateTask and setting my custom column value from CreateTaskProperties ExtendedProperties hash table.